# Windows batch file deletes and recopies files WAY too fast - should take 15+ seconds, takes < 1 second. Why?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I wrote a script that checks to see if a folder exists, and if so, empties it. it then waits 5 seconds, then proceeds to recopy new (or maybe the same) files back into the folder.

When the folders don't already exist, it'll take 15-20 seconds to copy the files. but when the folders already exist, I can watch them being emptied, I see it wait, then I see it zip through the copy commands in less than 1 second. And the files show up in the list.

Can someone explain this to me? It would almost appear that the copy is actually looking to see if the file HAD existed, and if so, if it was somehow identical, it just restores the file rather than recopy it.

I haven't tested the "restore" theory, but wanted to know if this was even probable (it's scary either way).

I added the 5 second pause thinking that maybe the drive needed time to stabilize.

Thanks in advance.

Example of script:

```
    @echo off
    if exist c:\some\folder erase /q c:\some\folder
    erase /q C:\another\folder\file*.exe
    ping -n 6 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul

    copy /y some\folder\sample.exe c:\some\folder\sample.exe
    copy /y another\folder\file001.exe c:\some\folder\file001
```

.exe

make your test files large so they take time to copy, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: If the source files are on slow media (network drive, USB drive, DVD) then you're just seeing caching - the source files are still in memory, so don't need to be read a second time.

Comment: There are two things in the universe which can not be quantified. The universe itself, and the speed of batch files.

Comment: I've spent the last hour trying to duplicate what I saw happen multiple times, but when specifically trying to test it, I can't make it happen, on FAT or NTFS, after a format, after a delete, or without the delete.

Comment: calling this dead.  thanks for the help.

Comment: It is a disk cache, as mentioned in the first comment.  if you copy a different folder every time then it will take the normal time to copy.  Repeat the copy and it is written from the disk cache - but note that the disk cache has a certain size.